# Viewing sleep pattern when there are more than one sleep period in one day in Fitbit app

Tags: applications

How can I view my sleep pattern when there are more than one sleep period in one day in Fitbit app?

E.g. below I only managed to see the 6h25 sleep period, but I can't see the 1h37 one.

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.